# Taking Number From button will not allow to enter more than two digit number

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am developing calculater , 
i use sender button tag value to get number from button..    user will not  able to enter more than two

digit value in textfield
i.e. 34+22 , 23+22 like this he will able   to enter,

234+234 like that he is not able to enter value in textfield. 
for that i use

```
-(IBAction)numberpress:(UIButton *)sender //number select

 {

     NSString *number = sender.currentTitle;
     self.caldisplay.text = [self.caldisplay.text stringByAppendingString:number];
     NSLog(@"%@ number is caldis",self.caldisplay.text);

 }
```

How i do this , help me thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
   -(IBAction)numberpress:(UIButton *)sender //number select

{
    NSString *number = sender.currentTitle;
    NSString *calculatingString = nil;
    if (self.caldisplay.text.length >= 2) {
        NSString *lastTwoChar = [self.caldisplay.text substringFromIndex:[self.caldisplay.text length] - 2];
        if ([lastTwoChar integerValue] >= 10) { // last char is content two number
            if ([number integerValue] > 0 || [number isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
                // invalid case. donothing here
                calculatingString = self.caldisplay.text;
            } else {
                calculatingString = [self.caldisplay.text stringByAppendingString:number];
            }
        } else {
            calculatingString = [self.caldisplay.text stringByAppendingString:number];
        }
    } else {
        calculatingString = [self.caldisplay.text stringByAppendingString:number];
    }

    // check valid input
    if ([self calculate:calculatingString] > 100) {
        // invalid case. donothing here
    } else {
        self.caldisplay.text = calculatingString;
    }
    NSLog(@"%@ number is caldis",self.caldisplay.text);
}

- (NSInteger)calculate:(NSString *)input {
    // you need to wite code calculating string here
    // example code to calculate only operator '+'
    NSArray *operands = [input componentsSeparatedByString:@"+"];
    NSInteger result = 0;
    for (NSString *operand in operands) {
        result = result + [operand integerValue];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: its giving me exception index out bound @A Bao

Comment: yes its working now @A Bao, one more issue can i ask

Comment: user will not bale to make addition more than 100, if 66+34=100 ok, 66 + 44 = 110 add goes to 100 then second number he will not able to enter like this

Comment: @iAsmi I can't understand your question. please more explain to me

Comment: user will not make addition more than 100. means 1st number i enter is 66 and 2nd number i enter is 34 , the add of this two number is 100 is this ok , but 1st number may 33 and 2nd number may 88 then add goes beyond 100 than it will not allow me to enter 2nd more 66 , which add goes to 100

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93963/discussion-between-iasmi-and-a-bao).

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this

```
- (IBAction)btnNumberClicked:(UIButton*)aButton
{
    if([self.caldisplay.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
    {
        self.caldisplay.text = aButton.currentTitle;
    }    
    else
    {
        self.caldisplay.text = [self.caldisplay.text stringByAppendingString:aButton.currentTitle];
    }
}
```

Comment: nop it will allow me to enter number more than three @Mayur Shrivas